# How to determine the units of the terms of a function relating two physical quantities?

Tags: kinematics, dimensional-analysis

While studying kinematics I came across a problem which said,

> A particle is moving along X-axis, its position $x$ varying with time $t$ as $x(t) = 2t^3 - 3t^2 + 1$.

Now, that is not the full problem but my point is that we know we can only add quantities which have the same dimensions and that the dimensions of both sides of an equation must be equal. However, if we look at the given equation then on the LHS, $$[x(t)] = L$$ whereas on the RHS we have, $$[t^3] = T^3, [t^2] = T^2, [1] = 1$$

Thus, the equation is not dimensionally consistent. So my question is if this can be rewritten as, $$x(t) = (2t^3)ms^{-3} -(3t^2)ms^{-2} + 1m$$

Also, would it be correct to write velocity $v$ as, $$v(t) = (6t^2)ms^{-3} - (6t)ms^{-2}$$

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @ConnorBehan Hi, am sorry I missed this earlier. Thank you for the verification but as Riccardo Gandolfo said, it will be correct without explicitly mentioning the units too, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say we can only sum quantities having the same dimensions.

We cannot write, as you would have liked, the position as a sum of terms with different dimensions. The only way to make sense of the given formula for $x(t)$ is realizing that the coefficients are not pure numbers but have dimension of their own.

2 is really 2 $ms^{-3}$

-3 is really  $-3 \ ms^{-2}$

1 is really 1 $m$

This way the formula makes sense. Usually there would be coefficients rappresented by letters for the sole purpose of making the dimensions "add up" without creating similar confusion with pure numbers, in this case though they were not used.

Comment: Oh, okay. So in this case, each coefficient (implicitly) has the correct dimensions to make the equation dimensionally consistent? Means that the equation is correct even if I don't mention units explicitly? I apologise if I misunderstood what you said

Comment: Exactly, the dimensions are included in the coefficients implicitly